# How to construct a data.frame with name for rows and columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I can construct a `data.frame` using the following code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-03-01"), to= as.Date("2001-05-31"), by="day"),
                     A = runif(92, 0,10),
                     D = runif(92,5,15),
                     Z = runif(92,3,15))
```

I, however, would like to construct a `data.frame` like in the `figure` below where the name of the `columns (I.e., 1:2 or 1:5)` and `rows (I.e., A, Z etc)` should be like what I have but the values can be `random` in there. I am trying to put a `reproducible` questions but wanted to first get my `data.frame` right.

[image]

Comment: What is the column names `1:2` or `1:5`

Comment: `1:2`, `1:5`,`1:10` etc are the column names

Comment: From the example, it is not clear

Comment: Do you need `DF %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Date, values_from = value)`

Answer (score 2):

If we want to transpose the dataset, in tidyverse, we reshape into 'long' format and reshape back to 'wide' with a different name column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = Date, values_from = value)
```

Comment: your answer did not completely answer my question but gave me other good ideas that would help me posting my reproducible question. Thank you.

Comment: @Hydro By reading your question, I was under the assumption that it is not a reproducible example of the expected because the `1:2` or `1:5` was not showed as values

Answer (score 1):

We can try reshaping using `reshape2::recast`.

```r
library(reshape2)
recast(DF, id.var = 1, variable ~ Date)
```

However, this will give us each date as a separate column; that is as far as we can help without a reproducible example.